# Understanding Number of Feature Classes vs Connection Time with Enterprise Geodatabases

Tags: arcgis-10.2, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, performance

So here's the situation - at the moment I am having a problem where the more feature classes I load into a ArcGIS 10.2 enterprise geodatabase in PostgreSQL, the slower the connection time becomes.  I have gone from 40 seconds with 2000 feature classes (both vector and raster) to 2 minutes with 6000 feature classes.

Has anybody else noticed this problem when adding more feature classes, if so did you manage to overcome the problem, and how did you fix it?

Comment: As it stands your question appears to be a poll or survey of ArcSDE users rather than a question that describes what you are doing and where you are stuck.  I think your underlying question may be "Why does PostgreSQL appear to be slower to load via ArcSDE than Oracle?"

Comment: It is a kind of poll, but the poll results in themselves actually provide the answer to this problem.  However I have also asked for any solutions for connection time optimisations people may have found.

Comment: I have reworded.  But I still need to ask the mini questions.

Comment: If, by "dataset" you mean "feature dataset", then yes, poor performance would be expected from a database with tens of thousands of tables and thousands of FDS.  The question itself is still a poll, and not well-suited to GIS SE.

Comment: This is a Meta SE Q&A concerning polls: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff  I think that by prescribing poll responses as the way your question should be answered, focus is drawn away from your underlying (and more important) question of whether going "from 40 seconds with 2000 datasets to 2 minutes with 6000 datasets (in PostGres ArcSDE 10.2)" is to be expected.  We are upfront in the [Tour] that there should be only one question per question.

Comment: OK - I see your point, it's a great shame with such an active community we can't draw out some useful empirical research from poll like questions.  I think some questions can't be answered without a poll - because one answer to one question from one or two people can't give you a full answer.

Comment: @Vince - by dataset I mean it in a more generic way, i.e. featureclasses, rasters, tables, not featuredatasets.

Comment: This is not the first time the point has been made that databases are designed to manage rows, not tables. Linear [O(N)] performance degradation with 3x table increase is the best you could possibly achieve. There *will* be O(N*N) algorithms at play as well.

Comment: Yeh but hang on here - if you connect to either database using plain vendor RDBMS tools e.g. Oracle Developer or pgAdmin - the connection is near instaneous - it's ArcCatalog here that seems to be the problem - but I just want to know for sure.  Also I have been told by ESRI that the amount of datasets we have is unusual - and I'm not so sure thats the case, I think having 2000 datasets is not out of this world.

Comment: I also thought the poll was NOT subjective and actually set out to garner research data, in turn it would have been a sample of data that could have been summarised and gone some way to provide an answer.  Anyway the "poll" has gone.

Comment: Of course a database connection is instantaneous, but an ArcGIS connection is nothing like a database connection -- It needs to inventory and symbolize all the objects available (owned by any user).  If you add the requisite function calls on a database with a table count an order of magnitude in excess of best practice, you *usually* get a 5-10 minute wait.  If you won't accept that your database is unusually large, there will be no resolution to this question.

Comment: @Vince - fair enough, but ESRI doesn't say what the best practice amount of objects in a database is. In fact I think it's unaccpetable that ESRI charge a lot of money for a piece of software that can't perform on par/near par with the host RDBMS; it kind of undermines the whole reason for having an Enterprise ArcSDE in the first place.  Thanks for at least confirming that you would expect a degregation of performance - at least I'm starting to think it's not something we have done wrong on the database implementation side.  We just have to much data for ArcCatalog to cope. :(

Comment: There are likely many things wrong with your implementation (which you haven't described), but you can continue to believe that only external forces are involved if you wish.

Comment: @Vince - just such a wierd response, I'm not sure whether you are going out of your way to be rude and/or arrogant but it's certainly coming accross like it! Why are you assuming that it's likely we haven't implemented our db properly and I just haven't bothered to describe all the "wrong things" with my implementation - bizarre! I don't believe for one second there are "external forces" at play here - I know doing a trace on ArcCatalog, SDE connections produce lengthy queries to the DB, BUT more so with PostGres than Oracle. I suspect ArcCatalog is just not up to the job.